# Words in a rectangle c#

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I am trying to create rectangle from stars and put inside a text, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
string[] n = s.Split(' ');
int longest = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
{
    if(n[i].Length > longest)
    {
        longest = n[i].Length;
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= n.Length + 2; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j <= longest + 2; j++)
   {
       if (i == 1 || i == n.Length + 2 || j == 1 || j == longest + 2)
       {
            Console.Write("*");                      
       }
       if (i == 2 && j == 1)
       {
            Console.Write(n[0]);
       }
       else 
            Console.Write("");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I can put single word and it's fine but, if I will change the number of array index it doesn't work properly.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you, please, provide an *example* of the desired output? E.g. on `Hello My World!` input?

Comment: Wow, what a complex piece of software. I wonder what it does

Comment: Hi t.r, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  In addition to the desired output, please also be specific about the problem you are encountering.  Is the box not showing at all?  Is it not formatted the way you expect it?  This will help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Multi word version

```
  // please, think about variables' names: what is "n", "s"? 
  // longest is NOT the longest word, but maxLength  
  string text = Console.ReadLine();
  // be nice: allow double spaces, take tabulation into account
  string[] words = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  // Linq is often terse and readable
  int maxLength = words.Max(word => word.Length);

  // try keep it simple (try avoiding complex coding)
  // In fact, we have to create (and debug) top
  string top = new string('*', maxLength + 2);

  // ... and body:
  // for each word in words we should
  //   - ensure it has length of maxLength - word.PadRight(maxLength)
  //   - add *s at both ends: "*" + ... + "*"    
  string body = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words
    .Select(word => "*" + word.PadRight(maxLength) + "*"));

  // and, finally, join top, body and top 
  string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, top, body, top);

  // final output
  Console.Write(result);
```

For the `Hello My World!` input the output is

```
 ********
 *Hello *
 *My    *
 *World!*
 ********
```